# Grabbing the Value of a Dynamically Created Object

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am dynamically creating buttons from an API call that looks like this:

[image: image of my current display]

My goal is that when a button is clicked the inner text will display in the search bar above.

below is the code for this auto complete component:

```
const Autocomplete = (props) =>
{
    
    const btnSearch = (e) => {
        console.log(props.suggestions)
    }
    
    return(
        <>
            {props.suggestions.map((e) => (
                <button className={style.btn} onClick={btnSearch} key={e}>{e}</button>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}

export default Autocomplete;
```

The Autocomplete component is then being placed in a div as seen here:

```
return (
        <>
            <div className={style.container}>

                <div className={style.title_hold}>
                    <h1>turn one</h1>
                    <h2>a search engine and game companion for Magic: The Gathering</h2>
                    
                </div>
                

                <input className={style.search} type='text' placeholder='search for cards here...' value={search} onChange={handleInputChange} onKeyPress={handleSubmit}></input>

                <div className={style.btn_wrap}>
                    <Autocomplete suggestions={results} />
                </div>
                
                
                <div className={style.data_wrap} id='user_display'>
                    <div className={style.img_wrap}>
                        {photos}
                    </div>
                    
                    <div className={style.display_info}>
                        <h2>{card.name}</h2>
                        <h2>{card.type_line}</h2>
                        <h2>{card.oracle_text}</h2>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state variable in your parent component and then pass a function to the Autocomplete's button for the `onClick` which will then update the state in the parent. Something like this:

```
const Autocomplete = (props) => {    
    return(
        <>
            {props.suggestions.map((e) => (
                <button className={style.btn} onClick={() => props.setSearch(e)} key={e}>{e}</button>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}

export default Autocomplete;
```

Your parent component:

```
import React from 'react'

const ParentComponent = (props) => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState("")

  const handleClick = (textFromButtonClick) => {
    setSearchText(textFromButtonClick)
  }

  return (
        <>
            <div className={style.container}>

                <div className={style.title_hold}>
                    <h1>turn one</h1>
                    <h2>a search engine and game companion for Magic: The Gathering</h2>
                    
                </div>
                

                <input className={style.search} type='text' placeholder='search for cards here...' value={searchText} onChange={handleInputChange} onKeyPress={handleSubmit}></input>

                <div className={style.btn_wrap}>
                    <Autocomplete setSearch={handleClick} suggestions={results} />
                </div>
                
                
                <div className={style.data_wrap} id='user_display'>
                    <div className={style.img_wrap}>
                        {photos}
                    </div>
                    
                    <div className={style.display_info}>
                        <h2>{card.name}</h2>
                        <h2>{card.type_line}</h2>
                        <h2>{card.oracle_text}</h2>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default ParentComponent;
```

I took over your input value in the parent component, but without seeing any of your other code, I have no idea how you're managing that but you can likely merge it into this workflow to wire it up.